# .NET Debbuger : Not loading all symbols

Tags: .net, visual-studio, jit

With Visual Studio Pro 2019 (16.3.2), I create a new .net core console project.
I set a breakpoint on the first instruction in Program.Main.

When I start from VS, the breakpoint isn't hit and the output display :

```
'dotnet.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'D:\Projects\ConsoleApp2\ConsoleApp2\bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.1\ConsoleApp2.dll'. PDB Symbol reader could not be loaded.
```

It's the same result with all type of project(.NET Framework console, Winforms, ...). The debugger can't load the symbol.

The problem appeared after I modify VS from the installer.

I have installed the 'class designer'. But after, VS can't compile project. Then I have desinstalled the 'class designer'. Now, VS can't load symbol and hit breakpoint.

Any idea?

Comment: That update did not go well.  Reinstalling from scratch is the best way to repair the problem.

Comment: Update to Visual Studio 2019 16.3.3 has resolved the problem. I think the installer make a repair during the update.